# Applying a function to DataFrame-rows based on column-names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Let' say I have a DataFrame with a lot of columns `df`, and different functions `fn(...)` that can be applied to those columns to compute different results. Hereby, the column names fit the arguments of the functions:

```
import pandas as pd

def f1(A, C):
    return(A + C)

def f2(B, C):
    return(C - B)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns = ['A','B','C'])
```

To apply a function to each row, I can use the following line of code:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: f1(row['A'], row['C']), axis = 'columns')
```

However, as different functions take different input arguments, it is kind of annoying to specify them explicitly, so I am looking for a way so that `apply` recognizes which value to pass to the function based on the column name.
In R, the above line is much shorter and I find this extremly convenient:

```
df$result = pmap(df, f1)
```

Is there anything similar in Python?

Btw, I know that `apply` is  not recommended, but the functions are so complex that they are not vertorizable anyways (at least for me), and the above function-definition makes debugging much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [chrslg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76716805/14551500), I think the shortest way to accomplish this is to unpack `row` and rewrite `f1` such that unused arguments are passed to `**kwargs`:

```
import pandas as pd

def f1(A, C, **kwargs):
    return(A + C)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns = ['A','B','C'])

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: f1(**row), axis = 'columns')
```

Comment: Oh. Nice. I started by looking for this kind of solutions. (using `**rows`. Which is eventually what I did inside the decorator), but was stuck on the fact that you can't pass a `kwarg` that contains field not wanted by f: `def f1(A,C):...` then `f1(**{'A':1,'B':2,'C':3})` wouldn't work because it will complain that `f1` has no `B` parameter. For a moment I considered even the possibility to advice to define all functions as function of N parameters `def f1(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,...)` with all possible column names, and just don't use unneeded one. The decorator idea was just to "filter" the kwarg

Comment: so that it is possible to define `f` without a `B` parameter, and then avoid passing that `B` parameter. I simply didn't thought of that simple solution. Using this extra kwarg, indeed, just handle extra arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I probably ignore some easier way, but if your goal is to be able, on `apply` size, to simply pass a row to a function, and, on the function code size, to use arguments name as is, may be one way could be to use decorators.

I mean, assuming that you can't just write your functions to take rows as argument

The manual (without decorator) way being

```py
def f1(row):
    return row['A']+row['C']

def f2(row):
    C=row['C']
    B=row['B']
    return C-B
```

You can help to create that with this decorator

```py
def pmapize(*args):
    def inner(f):
        def g(row):
            return f(**{a:row[a] for a in args})
        return g
    return inner


@pmapize('A', 'C')
def f1(A, C):
    return(A + C)

@pmapize('B', 'C')
def f2(B, C):
    return(C - B)
```

Then you can use those functions with a row passed as argument. Since what this does is create a function `f1(row)` whose result is what you expect

```py
f1({'A':1, 'C':5})
# 6

f2({'A':1, 'C':18, 'B':10})
# 8
# Note that extra argument 'A' is ignored. Only B and C are passed to 
# the "inner" f2 
# And that argument order doesn't matter
```

Of course then you can use it as intended

```py
df.apply(lambda row: f1(row), axis = 'columns')
```

## Edit: a simplification using introspection

Using this decorator, that relies on introspection, you can even skip the passing of the arguments names, and just rely on the name
given to arguments directly

```py
def pmapize2(f):
    argsName=list(f.__code__.co_varnames)[:f.__code__.co_argcount]
    def inner(row):
        return f(**{a:row[a] for a in argsName})
    return inner
```

Then you can define your functions

```py
@pmapize2
def f3(D, F):
    return (D+2)*F
```

That function is in reality a function that expects a row as argument, and expect to find fields D and F in that row.

Therefore

```py
# With some random order, and extra (ignored) fields in the row
f3({'F':5, 'C':1, 'D':2, 'E':3})
# Returns 20
```

So, you can like before, just pass it to pandas.

## tl;dr

To summarize from your code

```py
import pandas as pd

def pmapize2(f):
    argsName=list(f.__code__.co_varnames)[:f.__code__.co_argcount]
    def inner(row):
        return f(**{a:row[a] for a in argsName})
    return inner

@pmapize2
def f1(A, C):
    return(A + C)

@pmapize2
def f2(B, C):
    return(C - B)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns = ['A','B','C'])

df['result'] = df.apply(f1, axis = 'columns') # Since `lambda row: f1(row)` is just `f1`
```

result:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C  result
0  1  2  3       4
1  4  5  6      10
2  7  8  9      16
```

Comment: Nice! Actually, unpacking also works directly in `apply` (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can execute them together under one function and call the correct columns there and use the `result_type = 'expand'` to split that output to multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns = ['A','B','C'])

def fn(row):
    outputs = []

    if 'A' and 'C' in row.index:
        outputs.append(f1(row.A, row.C))
    if 'B' and 'C' in row.index:
        outputs.append(f2(row.B, row.C))
        
    return outputs

def f1(A, C):
    return(A + C)

def f2(B, C):
    return(C - B)

# Adjusted for variable number of resulting columns
df[[f'results{i}' for i in range(len(results.columns))]] = results
```

Comment: interesting, but not exactly what I was looking for. In fact, not all my Dataframes have each column, and consequently I don't want to apply every function to each dataframe

Comment: I see, I've edited the answer to account for the presence/absence of columns.